# Libreoffice Writer: How to set different colors to each letter?

Tags: fonts, libreoffice-writer

I'm writing some reading material for a dislexic kid. To ease things for him, I want to use different colors in each letter (i.e. all "a" in red, all "e" in blue, etc).

I'm doing it manually, and it is a pain. Tried to use search/replace, but it does not accept colors or formatting.

Is there any way define a color for each letter?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a python macro:

```py
import string

def get_color_dict():
    color_list = []
    #color_range = range(0xFF + 1)  # all possible colors
    color_range = [0, 128, 200]
    for r in color_range:
        for g in color_range:
            for b in color_range:
                color_list.append("%02x%02x%02x" % (r, g, b))
    letter_color = {}
    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        letter_color[letter] = color_list.pop(0)
    return letter_color

def colorize_text():
    letter_colors = get_color_dict()
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oVC = doc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    oVC.gotoStart(False)
    oVC.collapseToEnd()
    while oVC.goRight(1, True):
        letter = oVC.getString()
        if letter:
            letter = letter.lower()
        if letter in letter_colors:
            oVC.CharColor = int(letter_colors[letter], 16)
        oVC.goRight(0, False)  # deselect
        oVC.collapseToEnd()

# Functions that can be called from Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro.
g_exportedScripts = colorize_text
```

To run the macro, save it as a plain text file.  Create a `Scripts/python` subfolder and put the file in it, as explained [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language).

Here are example results using "Lorem ipsum" (following @tohuwawohu):

[image]

Comment: Very nice approach! No multiple find/replace, no need to set colors manually... +1!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the only way to achieve this is by doing a search/replace, assigning the font color when replacing. To automatically change the character color when replacing, open the `Find & replace` dialog (Menu `Edit` -> `Find & Replace`, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), and select "`Other Options`":

[image]

Now, there's a button <kbd>Format</kbd>:

[image]

A click on the <kbd>Format</kbd> button will bring up the usual character style dialog. There, switch to the "Font effects" tab and set the font color for the specific character:

[image]

After selecting the color, it will be displayed below the "Replace with" combobox (to remove it, click the <kbd>No Format</kbd> button):

[image]

Here's the result of replacing `a` and `e` by themselves this way, with a custom font color, in a `Lorem ipsum` text:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on tohuwawohu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37260744/731314), but I don't think I can pull it off in a comment.  The Python macro approach still would've been better, but I was unable to get Libre to recognize them.

- Check the "Regular Expressions" box
- In the search box, type `(e)` and `($1)` in the replace box

  - This will replace each match with itself; It's effectively the same as putting "e" in both boxes, but now you only have to change one of them each time).  Additionally, as long as "Match case" is unchecked, it will take care of "e" and "E" without losing their case.
- Finally I went one step further and decided I was fine with only using 5 different colors and chunked the letters into character classes.  To do this, use something like `([abcde])`, `([fghij])`, etc in the search field; every letter within the square brackets will be given the chosen format.